# While Loop (Python 3.7.4)

Tags: python, while-loop

I am a student new to programming things in Python and there's a problem I'm having with understanding how to get Python to work with this While Loop for the equation given to me.

The problem states:

> a^x may be evaluated with the following series:
>   `a^x = 1 + x*ln(a) + ((x*ln(a))^2/2! + ((x*ln(a))^3/3! + ... + ((x*ln(a))^n/n!`
>
> a = 1.52
>
> x = 3.14
>
> Continue your series until the Absolute Term is less than 10^-6 or you have computed 100 terms.
>
> Output your series of a^x, the number of terms used (n)

What I Tried on Python 3.7.4:

```
from math import *

outFile = open("HW3out.txt", "a")
print("Problem 4 soln",file = outFile)

maxt = 100
tol = 1e-6
x = 3.14
a = 1.52
z = (x*log*a)

term = z
n = 1
sum = z

while abs(term) < tol and n < maxt:
   n = n+1
   term = (x*log*a)**n/n
   sum = sum + term

a**x = sum
diff = a**x - a

print("a^x", a**x, " Correct Value ", a, file = outFile)
print("x ", x, "n ", n, "term ", term, "diff ", diff, file = outFile)

outFile.close()`
```

I know that I did something wrong with my code but I don't understand what. I used the example from my professor with a different equation he did in class but I still couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: How do you know you did something wrong? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Immediately obvious issue: `log` is a function, not a constant of some sort. `x * log * a` is nonsensical, because multiplying a number by a function is nonsensical. I suspect you want `x * log(a)`, which calls `log` on `a`, and returns a new number that can be multiplied by `x`.

Comment: Also `a**x` is an expression, and you can't assign sum to it

Comment: Give the error you are getting

Comment: Seems you need: z = x * log(a), and when you update term in the while loop you need: term = term * z / n

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question. If you solved your problem, post an answer and (eventually) accept it.

Answer (score 0):

After looking back at feedback, I found that one of the problems was my

```
a**x = sum
```

which i deleted and someone else suggested me to use `term = term*z**n/n` instead of `term = (x*log*a)**n/n`
This is what my new file looks like now:

```
from math import *

outFile = open("HW3out.txt", "a")
print("Problem 4 soln",file = outFile)

maxt = 100
tol = 1e-6
x = 3.14
a = 1.52
z = (x*log(a))

term = z
n = 1
sum = z

while abs(term) < tol and n < maxt:
   n = n+1
   term = term*z**n/n
   sum = sum + term


diff = a**x - a

print("a^x", a**x, " Correct Value ", a, file = outFile)
print("x ", x, "n ", n, "term ", term, "diff ", diff, file = outFile)


outFile.close()
```

I got from my `outFile`

```
Problem 4 soln
a^x 3.7238215950300577  Correct Value  1.52
x  3.14 n  1 term  1.314750451454701 diff  2.2038215950300577
```

which I think is correct since the program is finally running now with no errors

Comment: I suggested term = term * z / n (not term = term * z**n/ n).  How small is your final error i.e. abs(a**x - [final value of sum in while loop])?